# Which server platform to choose: SQL Azure or Hosted SQL Server for new project

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We're getting ready to build a new platform for our current system. Currently we install sql server express locally to all our clients and all their data is stored there. While the process works pretty good, it's still a pain to add columns/tables etc. We also want to have our data available outside of the local install. So we're moving to a central web based sql database and creating a web based application. Our new application will be a Silverlight 5, wcf ria services, mvvm, entity framework application

We've decided that either a web hosted sql server database or sql azure database are the way to go. However, I have no idea why I would choose one over the other. The limitations of azure don't seem to apply to us, but our application will be run on our current shared web host. Is it better to host the application on the same server as the database? Do we even know with shared web hosting that the server is on the same location as the app? There's also the marketing advantage of being 'in the cloud' which our clients love when we drop that word (they have no idea about anything technical, it's just a buzzword for them). I'm not too worried about the cost as I think both will ultimately be about the equivalent of each other.

I feel like I may be completely overthinking this and either will work, however I'd like to try and get the best solution for us and don't want to choose without getting some feedback.

In case it helps, our application is mostly dashboard/informational data. Mostly financial and trending data. It's almost entirely read only. Sometimes the data can get fairly large and we would be sending upwards of 50,000 rows of data to the application.

Thanks for any help/insight you can provide for me!

Comment: @Aaron: Just edited the original post. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem. Now watch as you can delete comments too, to keep the dialog clean. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Are you satisfied now? :-) Just kidding of course, thanks for helping a stackoverflow newb out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main concerns I would have with using a SQL Azure DB from an application on your current shared web host would be

1. The effect of network latency: Depending on location, every time you do a DB round trip from your application to the SQL Azure DB you will incur a 50-100ms delay. If your application does lots of round trips, this will mount up. Often, if an application has been designed to work with a DB on the LAN (you use of local client DBs suggests this) the they tend to get "chatty" since network delays are very small on the LAN. You may find your application slows down significantly.
2. Security: You will have to open up the SQL Azure firewall to the IP address(es) that your application presents when querying. Depending on your host, it may be that this IP address is shared between several tenants. This would be a vulnerability.

If neither of these is a problem, then SQL Azure will provide a much lower management overhead (e.g. no need to patch etc.) and will give you very high reliability, especially in terms of the risk of data loss.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I should have clarified that we're building a new application as well: Silveright 5 using wcf ria services, mvvm, and entity framework. So, based on that are points 1 and 2 still a concern? Regarding point 2 I think what your saying is we would need a dedicated ip address that is just used by us?

Comment: +1 but let's not forget the feature gap. While Azure already has some of the new SQL Server 2012 T-SQL syntax, many of the features aren't available yet (including some 2008/2008 R2 functionality), and some features will never be in the cloud (since they don't make sense there).

Comment: @Essential. Since you are building a new application, you should be able to design out the latency problem - just be aware of it though. Your solution WILL be slower than it would be with the data co-located with the application.

Comment: @Essential: The important IP address is the one that your application presents when it is querying the DB. Depending on proxy servers etc. this could vary.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Good point - it always needs to be checked. Without more detail it's hard to know if any of the feature gaps are an issue, but the OP said "The limitations of azure don't seem to apply to us" so I assumed they'd researched it :o)

Comment: I thought that statement was a bit vague and potentially ambiguous - might have meant limitations in resources, such as I/O inflexibility, CPU/RAM, network, etc. Just wanted *feature* limitations to be explicitly stated somewhere.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Regarding the feature limitations, when going through the unsupported list we didn't see anything that would affect us. Hopefully that's not because of our ignorance.

Comment: @Essential I hope so too. And I hope you aren't offended that I wasn't sure that's what you meant. :-)

Comment: @MikeGoodwin: Thanks for all the info and especially the ip concern.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Not offended at all :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Just wanted to add, I actually appreciate when someone makes sure that everyone understands what we're working with. So I'm glad you did clarify that point.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin: Regarding the latency, that is my biggest concern. We may just have to run tests with both to decide. If we have to manage the db ourselves, but the latency is much better than that might be what we do. If sql azure proves to be speedy enough, then we'll go with that.